# Como posso converter o timestamp e o decimal para lista

Tags: python, json, api

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2b0X.jpg)

Como posso converter o timestamp e o decimal para lista?
A api so aceita a informação em formato total json.

Comment: Olá! Evite postar prints de código. Sempre prefira postar código no formato texto, devidamente formatado como código. Isso aumenta suas chances de obter a ajuda solicitada.

Comment: a sim, muito obrigado